# JavaFX. Can't remove extra-space at the right of TabPane

Tags: css, user-interface, tabs, javafx-2, tabpanel

I'm developing full-screen application on JavaFX 2.2 with tab navigation. Tab's should fill all screen width. But I found that I have 10px space at the right side of headers region.. And what's interesting: this space appear only after I switch to the last tab and disappear only after I will switch to the first tab. Other tabs don't change this space, it's appear, only after selecting last tab, and disappear after selecting first one. Here the screenshots which explain the issue (this margin is yellow):

[image]

[image]

Tab's width I calculating by the simple formula:

```
double tabWidth = tabPane.getWidth() / tabPane.getTabs().size();
tabPane.setTabMinWidth(tabWidth);
tabPane.setTabMaxWidth(tabWidth);
```

All padding's removed in CSS-classes. Also i set special colors, to understand who is the owner of this space.. and looks like it's the main *headers-region*. Here the CSS-calsses:

```
.tab-pane .headers-region {
 -fx-background-color: yellow;
 -fx-padding: 0;
 -fx-background-insets: 0;
 -fx-effect: null;
}

.tab-pane {
 -fx-background-color: white;
 -fx-background-insets:0;
 -fx-padding: 0;
}

*.tab-header-background {
 -fx-padding:0;
 -fx-background-insets:0;
}

.tab-pane *.tab-header-background {
 -fx-padding:0;
 -fx-background-insets:0;
}

.tab:selected {
 -fx-background-color: white;
 -fx-background-insets: 0;
 -fx-background-radius: 0;    
}

.tab {
 -fx-background-color: white;
 -fx-padding: 0;
 -fx-background-insets: 0;   
}

.tab:top {
 -fx-padding: 0;
 -fx-background-insets: 0;
}

.tab:right {
 -fx-padding: 0;
 -fx-background-insets: 0;
}

.tab:bottom {
 -fx-padding: 0;
 -fx-background-insets: 0;
}

.tab:left {
 -fx-padding: 0;
 -fx-background-insets: 0;
}

.tab:hover {
 -fx-padding: 0;
 -fx-background-insets: 0;
}

.tab-header-area {
 -fx-padding: 0;
 -fx-background-insets: 0;
}

.tab-pane:top *.tab-header-area {
 -fx-background-insets: 0;
 -fx-padding: 0;
}

.tab-pane:bottom *.tab-header-area {
 -fx-background-insets: 0;
 -fx-padding: 0;
}

.tab-pane:left *.tab-header-area {
 -fx-background-insets: 0;
 -fx-padding: 0;
}

.tab-pane:right *.tab-header-area {
 -fx-background-insets: 0;
 -fx-padding: 0;
}

.control-buttons-tab {
 -fx-background-insets: 0;
 -fx-background-radius: 0;
 -fx-padding: 0;
}

.tab-down-button {
 -fx-background-color: green;
 -fx-padding: 0;
}

.tab-down-button .arrow {
 -fx-background-insets: 0;
 -fx-background:black;
 -fx-width:0;
 -fx-padding: 0;
 -fx-shape: " ";
}

.arrow {
 -fx-background-insets: 0;
 -fx-background:black;
 -fx-width:0;
 -fx-padding: 0;
 -fx-shape: " ";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the class TabPaneSkin, which converts Tabs into Nodes.
It needs to scroll the TabHeaderArea to the left (or the right) when his offset is greater than his width.
Look at the method `scrollToSelectedTab(double selected, double previous)` in the class TabHeaderArea.

The only way I've found to solve this is to create your custom MyTabPaneSkin (inspired from TabPaneSkin) and change the behavior of the method `scrollToSelectedTab` (As all of its members are private, extending it would not be helpful).

Then, override the method `createDefaultSkin` of the class TabPane like this:

```
TabPane tabPane = new TabPane(){
    @Override
    protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
        return new MyTabPaneSkin(this);
    }   
};
```

Keep in mind that you will lose all improvements or fixes from the original TabPaneSkin.

Ideally, JavaFX should implement this feature by allowing to disable the autoscroll...

(See https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-38014)

Comment: good dig! feels like a bug to me though - shouldn't behave differently on selection. You or @VadymTretyak might consider filing an report in fx' issuetracker

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" it for my use case using reflection to access the `TabePaneSkin.TabHeaderArea.setScrollOffset`.

It's not great having to use reflection but I personally prefer it over re-implementing the whole `TabPaneSkin`.

```
private static void resetAutomaticScrollingOfTabPaneHeaders(TabPane tabPane) throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
    Skin<?> skin = tabPane.getSkin();
    TabPaneSkin tabPaneSkin = (TabPaneSkin) skin;

    // TabePaneSkin.TabHeaderArea
    Node tabHeaderArea = tabPaneSkin.getChildren().get(tabPaneSkin.getChildren().size() - 1); // The TabHeaderArea seems to be the last child of the TabPaneSkin.

    Method setScrollOffset = tabHeaderArea.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setScrollOffset", double.class);
    setScrollOffset.setAccessible(true);
    setScrollOffset.invoke(tabHeaderArea, 0);
}
```

You could call this from a width listener, e.g.

```
widthProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    try {
        resetAutomaticScrollingOfTabPaneHeaders(this);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        log.warn("Could not scroll the TabHeaderArea back to the left.", e);
    }
});
```

Comment: I came here from https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8091334, which is still marked as open, so I think this is still a relevant question.

Answer (score 0):

I have improved the function to remove the appearance of the space when clicking on the last tab :)

```
private static void resetAutomaticScrollingOfTabPaneHeaders(TabPane tabPane)
            throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {
        Skin<?> skin = tabPane.getSkin();
        TabPaneSkin tabPaneSkin = (TabPaneSkin) skin;

        // TabePaneSkin.TabHeaderArea
        Node tabHeaderArea = tabPaneSkin.getChildren().get(tabPaneSkin.getChildren().size() - 1); // The TabHeaderArea seems to be the last child

        // TabePaneSkin.TabHeaderArea.scrollOffsetDirty
        Field scrollOffsetDirty = tabHeaderArea.getClass().getDeclaredField("scrollOffsetDirty");
        scrollOffsetDirty.setAccessible(true);
        scrollOffsetDirty.setBoolean(tabHeaderArea, false);

        // TabePaneSkin.TabHeaderArea.setScrollOffset()
        Method setScrollOffset = tabHeaderArea.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setScrollOffset", double.class);
        setScrollOffset.setAccessible(true);
        setScrollOffset.invoke(tabHeaderArea, 0);
    }
```